# Corrupted x86 files on a Windows 7 standard account

Tags: windows-7, firefox, file-corruption

I have a Dell laptop with Windows 7 Professional that has corrupted (x86) files-program files that causes Firefox and some other apps to freeze up. I can't use Firefox to surf the web or some other apps, like music editing software, etc. that use the (x86) files, but everything else works fine on my laptop. I can play CDs and DVDs on it, stream/listen to music, or use other web browsers like Google Chrome and Internet Explorer to get on the web.

Is there a kernel issue, a corrupt driver (x86) or some other internal issue here? I scanned/checked for viruses/malware with my security software and found none whatsoever, but I downloaded music software that fouled up the (x86) files last month. I tried everything I could to fix the situation on my own.

What do you think the problem really is? Your best advice/help to me is what can I do on my own and how to do it to solve this problem.

Answer (score 1):

You "downloaded music software that fouled up the (x86) files last month". Even a Windows 7 repair install could leave some malware behind from the same music program that fouled up the x86 files. Windows 7 will be unsupported in another 12 days, and if you make a mistake when trying to fix this problem you're running out of time to correct it.

Now would be a good time to consider the option of reinstalling Windows 7. The option of updating Windows 7 with updates from Microsoft will only be available for another 12 days. After 12 days you can reinstall Windows 7, but there won't be any more free updates from Windows Update service for it. A new installation of Windows that can't receive free updates from Windows Update service is easier to hack than an updated Windows operating system. Some Windows users wouldn't want to use it at all.

Answer (score 0):

Run a Windows 7 Repair Install from the Windows 7 DVD or the onboard Recovery Partition. Here is a tutorial to help you.

http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/3413-repair-install.html

You need the same edition of DVD as is installed on your computer now.

Here are the first few steps of the tutorial

> 1. Start Windows 7, and log on to an administrator account.
> 2. Disable any 3rd party firewall, antivirus, or other security program to avoid it from possibly preventing the repair in-place
>      upgrade installation of Windows 7.
> 3. Do either step 4, step 5, or step 6 below depending if your retail Windows 7 installation ISO/DVD/USB has SP1 or not, and if your
>      currently installed Windows 7 has SP1 installed or not.
> 4. Repair Installed Windows 7 SP1 using Windows 7 with SP1 ISO

Comment: Probably can be fixed by a sfc/ scannow, less invasive than a repair install.